# How to determine probability of words?

Tags: python, linux, probability

I have two documents. Doc1 is in the below format:

```
TOPIC:  0 5892.0
site 0.0371690427699
Internet 0.0261371350984
online 0.0229124236253
web 0.0218940936864
say 0.0159538357094

TOPIC:  1 12366.0
web 0.150331554262
site 0.0517548115801
say 0.0451237263464
Internet 0.0153647096879
online 0.0135856380398
```

...and so on till Topic 99 in the same pattern.

And Doc2 is in the format:

```
0 0.566667 0 0.0333333 0 0 0 0.133333 ..........
```

and so on... There are totally 100 values each value for each topic.

Now, I have to find the weighted average probability for each word, that is:

```
P(w) = alpha.P(w1)+ alpha.P(w2)+...... +alpha.P(wn)

where alpha = value in the nth position corresponding to the nth topic.
```

that is for the word "say", the probability should be

```
P(say) = 0*0.0159 + 0.5666*0.045+.......
```

Likewise for each and every word, I have to calculate the probability.

```
For  multiplication, if the word is taken from topic 0, then the 0th value from the doc2 must be considered and so on.
```

I have only performed counting of the occurrences of words with the below code, but have never taken their values. So, I am confused.

```
 with open(doc2, "r") as f:
    with open(doc3, "w") as f1:

         words = " ".join(line.strip() for line in f)
         d = defaultdict(int)
         for word in words.split():  
              d[word] += 1
              for key, value in d.iteritems() :
                  f1.write(key+ ' ' + str(value) + ' ')
              print '\n'
```

My output should look like:

```
 say = "prob of this word calculated by above formula"
 site = "
 internet = "
```

and so on.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming you are ignoring TOPIC lines, use a defaultdict to group the values and then do the calculation at the end:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import groupby, imap

d = defaultdict(list)
with open("doc1") as f,open("doc2") as f2:
    values = map(float, f2.read().split()) 
    for line in f:
        if line.strip() and not line.startswith("TOPIC"):
            name, val = line.split()
            d[name].append(float(val))

for k,v in d.items():
    print("Prob for {} is {}".format(k ,sum(i*j for i, j in zip(v,values)) ))
```

Another way would be to do the calcs as you go, increasing a count each time you hit a new section i.e a line with TOPIC to get the correct value from values by indexing:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(float)
from itertools import  imap

with open("doc1") as f,open("doc2") as f2:
    # create list of all floats from doc2
    values = imap(float, f2.read().split())
    for line in f:
        # if we have a new TOPIC increase the ind to get corresponding ndex from values
        if line.startswith("TOPIC"):
            ind = next(values)
            continue
        # ignore empty lines
        if line.strip():
            # get word and float and multiply the val by corresponding values value
            name, val = line.split()
            d[name] += float(val) * values[ind]

for k,v in d.items():
    print("Prob for {} is {}".format(k ,v) )
```

Using you two doc1 content and `0 0.566667 0 0.0333333 0` inside doc2 outputs the following for both:

```
Prob for web is 0.085187930859
Prob for say is 0.0255701266375
Prob for online is 0.0076985327511
Prob for site is 0.0293277438137
Prob for Internet is 0.00870667394471
```

You could also use itertools groupby:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(float)
from itertools import groupby, imap

with open("doc1") as f,open("doc2") as f2:
    values = imap(float, f2.read().split())
    # lambda x: not(x.strip()) will split into groups on the empty lines
    for ind, (k, v) in enumerate(groupby(f, key=lambda x: not(x.strip()))):
        if not k:
            topic = next(v) 
            #  get matching float from values
            f = next(values)
            # iterate over the group 
            for s in v:
                name, val = s.split()
                d[name] += (float(val) * f)
for k,v in d.iteritems():
    print("Prob for {} is {}".format(k,v))
```

For python3 all the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) `imaps` should be changed to just `map` which also returns an iterator in python3.

Comment: so  `say`  0.0159538357094 is multiplied by 5892.0? I only see you multiplying by the corresponding  element from your doc2 file in your question

Comment: No worries, you're welcome.  You had me a little confused :)

Comment: No prob, at least you made a good effort to solve it yourself which is more than a lot of people do on here ;)

Comment: I will have a look in the a.m but basically we just need to replace .read().split() with splitting each line then iterating over each, opening a file for each and writing the output.

Comment: Are you using the code exactly as posted and using python2?

Comment: @Rudhra, I have tried all the versions and they all work, add the traceback from the errors to pastebin  after running the code exactly as above

Comment: I am heading out for the afternoon and evening but it should not be much of an issue to change the code, just add a sample input to pastebin and the expected output and I will throw it together when I get back

Comment: Thank you so much Padraic. You are the best :) I don't know what a pastebin is :P I will read on it and try my best. Sorry to bother you again and again.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/, your problem is you seem to want to use a new dict for each section/TOPIC not actually get a total count

Comment: Add the full expected output to pastebin

Comment: Just add a small sample and what you expect as output for all

Comment: Why are you expecting 1? Are all the topics independant or what exactly?

Comment: Running your code I get nothing close to what is mentioned in the question, are you saying each topic should sum to 1?

Comment: upload it to google drive and share the folder, do the amount of topics and amount of floats in the second file math up?

Comment: Also how could topic_1 sum to 1 when all the values are 0?

Comment: what does the last number after each topic name signify?

Comment: Ok, one other thing should the sum of all the topic values equal 1 exactly?

Comment: Are you saying your code gives you .99999999999999 or > using `"assigned0_lda25_100.txt"` `"Buy_local_food_call_to_schools_normalized.txt"`?

Comment: You realise you only have 15 topics and 400 float values pairing `"assigned0_lda25_100.txt"` `"Buy_local_food_call_to_schools_normalized.txt"`?

Comment: Ok that returns `0.999999999999949`

Comment: Is there some logic that can verify that the data in the files is actually correct,should each topic and the txt file with the decimals all sum to ~1?

Comment: OK because I  cleaned your data down to only numbers >0.0 which makes it significantly smaller and I cannot see anything obvious

Comment: No worries, I am going to sign off for the night but I will have a look tomorrow again so if you discover anything in the meantime let me know.